# SQL DELETE FROM table records matching subquery

Tags: postgresql, subquery, sql-delete

I have a subquery that returns

```
 one_id   | two_id
--------------------
 1654838  | 1526634
 1657136  | 1526634
 1659179  | 1526634
 1659527  | 1526634
 2040608  | 1510944
 2040608  | 1516727
```

I have a table_x like

```
 one_id   | two_id  | other_column
-----------------------------------
 1654838  | 1526634 | ...
 ...      | ...     | ...
```

How can I DELETE records FROM table_x having `one_id` and `two_id` listed in subquery result?

If the subquery would return only `one_id` I could use something like

```
DELETE FROM table_x WHERE `one_id` IN (SELECT ...
```

Is there a similar solution with the given subquery result?

Comment: delete from  table_x where one_id=1654838 and two_id=1526634 ;

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

Yes, the below answer was not correct. I had the chance to test it. But this should work:

```
DELETE FROM
    mytable2 AS t1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT
        one_id, two_id
    FROM
        mytable1 t2
    WHERE
        t1.one_id=t2.one_id AND
        t1.two_id=t2.two_id
)
```

Update 2: Add an additional WHERE AND clause which will give you the wanted one_id and two_id values. Example:

```
    WHERE
        (t2.someothercol > 0 AND t2.someothercol < 10) AND
        t1.one_id=t2.one_id AND
        t1.two_id=t2.two_id
```

**Original answer**

<s>Maybe something like this (I couldn't test it though):</s>

```
WITH my_subquery AS (
    SELECT one_id, two_id
    FROM some_table
)
DELETE FROM table_X AS t1
WHERE t1.one_id=my_subquery.one_id AND t1.two_id=my_subquery.two_id
```

Reference to PostgreSQL documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html

Comment: I get [42P01] ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "subquery" Position: 834

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's the impact on performance but you can try something like:

```
DELETE FROM table_x WHERE CONCAT(one_id, two_id) IN (SELECT CONCAT(one_id, two_id) ...
```

Probably also casting and/or aliasing is needed.